# Invalid procedure call or argument error on ie8

Tags: javascript

I changed style of button using

```
onChanged: function () {
    var maximizeBtn = document.getElementById('maximizeBtn');
    maximizeBtn.style.left = maximizeBtn.style.left - 30;
},
```

its working on ie9,ie10,ie11 but not on ie8

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error message? What calls `onchanged`, where in the full code is it located? Also show the markup for the `#maximizeBtn`.

Comment: does `maximizeBtn.style.left = parseInt(maximizeBtn.style.left) - 30 + 'px';` work?

Comment: on maximizeBtn.style.left = maximizeBtn.style.left - 30;  line

Comment: The property `style.left` is not a number, it's a string terminated by `"px"`.

Comment: thanks for answer
let me check this 'maximizeBtn.style.left = parseInt(maximizeBtn.style.left) - 30 + 'px';'

Comment: On few machine its worked but failing for some machines

Comment: thanks guys
I used parseInt and its work